# how to open images in a dialog

Tags: android

earlier today i posted a question on how to open an image from a gallery.as a member answered i followed this tutorial http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gallery-imageview-example/...  my question now is,i would like to open the images in a dialog and no down of my gallery.is it possible?thanks

```
 private Integer[] mImageIds = {
            R.drawable.a,
            R.drawable.aa,
            R.drawable.aaa,
            R.drawable.aaaa

    };
      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        imgView.setImageResource(mImageIds[0]);

       Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
     g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                 imgView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);         }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) class. It is similar to an Activity:

```
new Dialog(this) {
    @Override
    public onCreate(Bundle unused) {
        ImageView myImage = new ImageView(getContext());
        myImage.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        setContentView(myImage);
    }
}.show();
```